# how to keep heroku dyno worker alive if web dyno goes to sleep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq, dyno

I have a web dyno that activates a worker dyno (sidekiq) to execute some tasks on the background. Some of these tasks take more than 30 minutes, and if the web dyno falls idle and goes down, the worker dyno goes down with it. How to keep the worker dyno working even if the web dyno that created it goes idle?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pay Heroku for their services?